# Unable to run python selenium webdriver scripts over Amazon EC2

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run a python script in which I am opening a webpage and clicking on some element. But the script is running very slow and giving random exceptions .

Mostly it halts at line
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

Message -

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'Can\'t load the profile. Profile ?Dir: /tmp/tmp4liaEq Firefox output: Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1733".\n1403086712970\taddons.xpi\tDEBUG\tstartup\n1403086713204\taddons.xpi\tDEBUG\tcheckForChanges\n1403086713568\taddons.xpi\tDEBUG\tNo changes found\n'

Sometimes - 
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='some_id']")`
Returning error that the element is not visible so can't be clicked.

The same script runs smoothly on my system that has 4GB RAM.
(EC2 system specs ~ 600mb memory)

I tried looking into the system and "top" command returned -

`604332k total,   577412k used,    26920k free,     6616k buffers`

I have installed firefox and also xvfb since i am running the firefox headlessly

Comment: @vipul Any idea what the problem might be ?

Comment: can you please add the code to the question?

Comment: sometimes the driver tries to click an element before the page is completely loaded in that case the element is not visible. To let the page load completely before clicking the element we use explicit waits (given in selenium docs) or just a simple `time.sleep`. And the code halting at `driver = webdriver.Firefox()` seems weird. Try re-installing selenium may be there's a problem with your version : `pip install -U selenium`

Comment: Have already tried all of these things but still facing the same problem !!
Selenium already up-to-date and Firefox version is 30.0

Comment: please add the code in the question then i'll try to run it on my machine

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. 
Running the scripts as root solved the problem.
Also making an user running the test a sudoer worked.